# Comma for independent clause

Tags: commas

> It is known that cookies are sugary, and that, therefore, cookies are delicious.

"Cookies are delicious" is an independent clause but "that cookies are delicious" is not.  How should I apply the rule for commas separating independent clauses?  Is it needed before "and?"  Thanks.

Comment: . It is known that cookies are sugary and, therefore, delicious. Your sentence is not pragmatically standard.

Comment: @Lambie It's a simplification of the longer sentence I was working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The commas around "therefore" are a parenthetical pair

You could, in principle, write it as:

> It is known that cookies are sugary, and that (therefore) cookies are delicious.

Writing it with commas avoids the excessive formality of the parentheses.

In other words, the commas there are not intended to mark out a dependent clause.

#### The comma before the "and" is not needed

Especially since there are two more commas coming shortly, you might remove it:

> It is known that cookies are sugary and that, therefore, cookies are delicious.